# Discovering the dependency relations among the samples of a data set

Tags: r, process

In the R environment;
Let say I have a data set similar to the one in below:

```
ID  Activity
1   a
1   b
2   a
3   c
2   a
1   c
4   a
4   b
3   b
4   c
```

As you can see each ID has a sequence of activities. What is important to consider is the number of times an activity is being followed by the other ones.
The results I am looking for are:
1. Discovering existing variants in the dataset (the existing sequence for each ID):
like: `

```
   <a,b, c> : id: 1 & 4
   <a,a>    : id: 2
   <c,b>    : id:3
```

2. A matrix as following which shows the number of times an activity is being followed by the other one:
   like:

   :`a  b  c
   a 1 2  0
   b 0 0  1
   c 0 1  0`

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with data.table

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(ID=c(1,1,2,3,2,1,4,4,3,4),Activity=c("a","b","a","c","a","c","a","b","b","c"))
```

1. IDs per Sequence:

   ```
   dt[,.(seq=paste(Activity,collapse = ",")),ID][,.(ids=paste(ID,collapse = ",")),seq]
   ```
2. We can get a fast answer:

   ```
   consecutive_id <- dt[,.(first=(Activity),second=(shift(Activity,type = "lead"))),ID][!is.na(second)]
   consecutive <- consecutive_id[,.N,.(first,second)]
   ```

   but if you need it in the matrix form a few extra steps are needed:

   ```
   classes <- dt[,unique(Activity)];n <- length(classes)
   M_consecutive <- data.table(matrix(0,nrow = n,ncol=n))
   setnames(M_consecutive,classes)
   M_consecutive$classes <- classes; setkey(M_consecutive,classes)
   for(i in 1:nrow(consecutive)) M_consecutive[consecutive[i]$first,(consecutive[i]$second):=consecutive[i]$N]
   M_consecutive
   ```